# unable to connect to the stream in Druid ingestion

Tags: streaming, druid, data-ingestion

unable to connect to the stream in Druid ingestion
I am unable to ingest the data into druid due to above error

when i check bootstrap servers and topic all are existing and they were connecting
the problem was with offset value
because the retention period at source is veryless

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If a streaming ingestion cannot resume consuming because the offset it is looking for is no longer in Kafka, you will need to do a hard reset on the streaming supervisor to reset the offsets. It is a good practice to have enough retention in kafka to survive streaming ingestion downtime in order to avoid this.